# How to switch between two opening Chrome windows (2 monitors) for data collecting purpose?

Tags: autohotkey

My everyday job is to open two Chrome windows on two monitors, copy data on the right window and paste it to the left one.

This script sometimes won't switch to the other window. I know there is a command called **WinActive** but I work on the same program **(google chrome)** so I don't know how to script this command.

Please help me to fix it, it's very unstable.

[This is my working place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu0fz.png)

```
1::     ; Copy name, change Capital then separate Last and First
Send, {CTRL DOWN}c{CTRL UP}   ; Copy data
sleep, 20
send, {Alt Down}{TAB}{Alt Up}     ; switch to the other Chrome window
sleep, 20
send, {CTRL DOWN}f{CTRL UP}
SendInput First      ;This is how I find the box to move the cursor to click on it
sleep, 5
PixelSearch px, py, 0, 95, 1132, 1019, 0x3296ff, 3, Fast   ; Find the color (of the First above)
MouseMove, %px%, %py% ; move mouse to color coordinates
Click
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
send, ^a      ; Select all text in the box
Clipboard := ""        ; Change capital letter and remove middle name
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 0
If ErrorLevel
Return
Sleep, 50
StringUpper str, Clipboard, T
head := SubStr( str, 1 , 1 )
tail := SubStr( str, 2 )
Clipboard := head RegExReplace( tail , "i)\b(de|an|and|in|the|with|of)\b", "$L1")
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "([A-Z][a-z]+) [A-Z][a-z]{0,2}\. ([A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1 $2")

Send, ^v
Send, {CTRL DOWN}{SHIFT DOWN}{LEFT DOWN}{SHIFT UP}{LEFT UP}x{CTRL UP}   ; Copy last name 
Send, {SHIFT DOWN}{TAB DOWN}{SHIFT UP}{TAB UP}{CTRL DOWN}v{CTRL UP}{TAB}{TAB}    ; bring last name to upper box,  then move to the third box

return
```

Many thanks for your reading and your time!

Comment: Try using [GroupAdd](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) and [GroupActivate](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupActivate.htm).

Comment: Can you help me with that please? I tried but it cycles all the opening tabs, not only the two windows that I'm working with.

GroupAdd, Chrome, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
return
Numpad1::

GroupActivate, Chrome, r

Comment: If you have more than 2 two windows, try adding the title: GroupAdd, Chrome, title1 ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 GroupAdd, Chrome, title2 ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 return.